# ListView is not visible on the output screen

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a ListView in which contents of an ArrayList(Declared Globally) is to be displayed. I am using  a custom layout here. Everything looks good but the ListView is just not showing on the output screen. While the same coding used on some other project is giving the desired output. Please tell me if there is any problem with the code or some other thing.

**Globalvar.java //where the ArrayList is declared**

```
package com.example.tale;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Globalvar
 {
    public static int value=0;
    public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

**activity_cart2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".cart2">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="404dp">

</ListView>
```

**cart2.java**

```
package com.example.tale;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class cart2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart2);

    Globalvar.list.add("Example 1");
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvl);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.forcart2,Globalvar.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

**forcart2.xml //custom layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="40sp">

</TextView>
```

Comment: If anyone else is having the same problem. Don't waste anymore time on this. I wasted my 4 days on this. Just try the same code on some another laptop. It will work absolutely fine. Though idk what was the problem with my Android Studio.

Comment: Some times things get wrong with the emulator too.try uninstall and install through gradle